# Hover-State at bottom of element

Tags: html, css, hover

I am currently developing a styleguide and the hover-state of my navigation is giving me some headache, but I am pretty sure, that it could be solved very easily, so I just want to ask, if someone has an idea.

My html looks like this:

```
<nav class='components__navigation'>
        <a href='../index.html'><img class='styleguide__logo' src='../imgs/Logo.png' alt='Logo'></a>
        <ul class='components__navListTop'>
            <li class='components__navItem'><a href='#'>Design</a></li>
            <li class='components__navItem' id='active'><a href='components.html'>Components</a></li>
            <li class='components__navItem'><a href='#'>Motionguide</a></li>
        </ul>
</nav>
```

and my css looks like this:

```
.components__navigation {
    display: flex;
    height: 75px;
    align-items: center;
    padding-left: 50px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #f5f5f5;
}

.components__navigation img {
    width: 250px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-right: 100px;
}

.components__navListTop {
    font-size: 14px;
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.components__navListTop a {
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: 50px;
}

.components__navItem a {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#ffda00,#ffda00),linear-gradient(#fff,#fff);
    background-size: 0 3px,auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom;
    transition: background .2s linear;
}

.components__navItem a:hover {
    background-size: 100% 3px,auto;
}

#active a {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#ffda00,#ffda00),linear-gradient(#fff,#fff);
    background-size: 100% 3px,auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom;
}
```

Here is a pen to make it more visual:
https://codepen.io/dbljn/pen/abbMdVE

The current hover-state is right under the font of the tabs, but I want the hover-state to be where the gray border is. Like so:
[image]

Do you have an idea? And thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always a good practice to write similar styling rules when the elements are overlapping on each other.
for example, we could use the same *background-image* property with *nav* html element instead of *border* property

```
.components__navigation {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding-left: 50px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(transparent 90%, #f5f5f5 0);
}
```

remove the margin from *ul* element and *background-image* from below selectors so that the *nav* element will spread on *li* element and will be dynamic

```
.components__navListTop {
    font-size: 14px;
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.components__navListTop a {
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

finally give the *li* element its background-image and other CSS rules,

```
.components__navItem {
    padding: 20px 0;
    margin-right: 50px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(transparent 90%,#ffda00 0);
    background-size: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom;
    transition: background .2s linear;
}
```

Since you want the animation while hovering on *li* element, the *:hover* pseudo attribute should be present on this *li* element, also it's good to use classes instead of id

```
.components__navItem:hover, .active {
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

Finally putting it all together,

```css
body, html {
    margin: 0;
}

.components__navigation {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding-left: 50px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(transparent 90%, #f5f5f5 0);
}

.components__navigation img {
    width: 250px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-right: 100px;
}

.components__navListTop {
    font-size: 14px;
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.components__navListTop a {
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.components__navItem {
    padding: 20px 0;
    margin-right: 50px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(transparent 90%,#ffda00 0);
    background-size: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom;
    transition: background .2s linear;
}

.components__navItem:hover, .active {
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav class='components__navigation'>
        <a href='../index.html'><img class='styleguide__logo' src='../imgs/Logo.png' alt='Logo'></a>
        <ul class='components__navListTop'>
            <li class='components__navItem active'><a href='#'>Design</a></li>
            <li class='components__navItem'><a href='components.html'>Components</a></li>
            <li class='components__navItem'><a href='#'>Motionguide</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `.components__navItem a` with:

```
.components__navItem a {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#ffda00,#ffda00);
    background-size: 0 3px,auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom;
    transition: background .2s linear;
    padding-bottom: 33px;
}
```

This is assuming a fixed font size though.

Comment: This works just fine, thank you! But it really is just a padding-bottom...how embarassing for me :D